# NotificationCompat.Builder setContentText throws exception for HTML text

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to create a notification using NotificationCompat.Builder. I am trying to use method

```
setContentText(Html.fromHtml(msg, null, new ListTagHandler()));
```

I have observed that when i have HTML text with **ul** and **li** tags in my text, i am unable to create a notification and it throws the exception even when i have handled the text using TagHandler. Following is the exception

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.xxxxx: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification
```

Any suggestion on how to resolve this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some debugging, i found the reason for the exception and the solution.

I was making a below function call for creating a notification

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.store_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText(
                        Html.fromHtml(msg, null, new ListTagHandler()));
```

Some of the devices were throwing exception while creating the msg on a notification Window as they can't expand tags like **ul** and **li** If these tags are received, Notification Builder object was throwing exception during the creation of remote views. When i removed the text with such HTML tags, it started showing the output correctly.